# Converting For Loop from C++ to R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert this c++ code to R:

```
 int nrow = df.nrow(), ncol = df.ncol();
  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
      dat[i * ncol + j] = data[j * nrow + i];
    }
  }
```

I wrote the following codes in R:

```
df = cbind(x = c(0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0), y = c(0.8,1.0,0.6,0.4,0.0,0.2)))

nRows <- nrow(df)
nCols <- ncol(df)

dat <- vector(mode="numeric", length= nRows * nCols) 

for (i in 1:nRows) {
  for (j in 1:nCols) {
      dat[i * nCols + j] <- df[j * nRows + i]
    }
}
```

But its not giving me the desired output.

i want to get this:

```
> dat
  [1] 0.0 0.8 0.2 1.0 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.0 1.0 0.2
```

but instead im getting this:

```
> dat
  [1] 0.0 0.0 0.8  NA 1.0  NA 0.6  NA 0.4  NA 0.0  NA 0.2  NA
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Based on the expected result `c(t(df))`

Comment: yes its a transpose but i want to understand the for loop iteration.

Comment: thanks im new to the programming language

Comment: `dat[(i-1) * nCols + j] <- df[(j-1) * nRows + i]`

Comment: @Khashaa it works please can you answer it and explain to me what was my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a vector that combines two vectors, where the values of the new vector are the values of the old vectors but alternating.

```
> # Make the vectors
> x = c(0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0)
> y = c(0.8,1.0,0.6,0.4,0.0,0.2)
> # Get the column positions and offset them
> x_col_pos = (seq_along(x) * 2) - 1
> y_col_pos = (seq_along(y) * 2)
> # Find the order of the positions to re-arrange the new vector
> z_col_pos = order(c(x_pos, y_pos))
> z = c(x, y)[z_col_pos]
[1] 0.0 0.8 0.2 1.0 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.0 1.0 0.2
```

This can be easily converted into a function.